# Other places or the other places

Tags: word-choice

Isn't it wrong to list interesting places as in text A before *the Nasca lines in Peru* without adding *other places*?

> **A:** There are so many unusual and beautiful places in the world I can't name the best. One of the famous places is Venice in Italy. It's also beautiful there. The Nasca lines in Peru, Thor's well in the USA, Lake Hillier in Western Australia.

Should it be  "other places" or "the other places"?

> **B:** There are so many unusual and beautiful places in the world I can't name the best. One of the famous places is Venice in Italy. It's also beautiful there. Other places are The Nasca lines in  Peru, Thor's well in The USA, Lake Hillier in Western Australia.

Comment: I think it's *The other places [I like] are ...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your A-text is incorrect. The sentence in question (which lists other places) is a sentence fragment that contains only objects, and does not have a subject or verb.

If you were to start the sentence with ***the* other places** that would imply that you *only* consider the places mentioned to be "unusual and beautiful," and that there are no other such places in the world. Using **other places** or **some other places** means you are listing non-exhaustive examples.

There are some other errors as well: both "Nasca Lines" and "Thor's Well" need to have both words capitalized, as they are proper nouns (specific named locations); and the "the"s in "the Nasca Lines' and "the USA" do not need to be capitalized.
The list sentence needs to have a conjunction like "and" or "or" before the last item (Lake Hillier).
"It's also beautiful there" is not incorrect but is a little jarring; I would say something like "...Venice in Italy, which is also beautiful."

Comment: Yes, I agree with this.  I would also add that instead of putting something at the beginning of that last sentence, one could put a comma after Australia with some words to clarify.  Something like "...Australia, are only a few of my favorite."

Comment: "If you were to start the sentence with the other places that would imply that you only consider the places mentioned to be "unusual and beautiful," and that there are no other such places in the world. Using other places or some other places means you are listing non-exhaustive examples."  Sorry, I want to make sure I understand correctly. By saying "the other places" I say that only the listed places are unusual and beautiful, but "the other places" aren't. By saying "other or some other places" I mean "other or some other places"  are also unusual and beautiful like the places I listed.

Comment: I would suggest "Other _beautiful_ places are...".  Every town in the world is an 'other place' than Venice.

Comment: @Antonia: if you say "Some places are beautiful, like Place A. **The** other places are B, C, and D" then you are are saying *no other place anywhere* is beautiful besides A/B/C/D. If instead you say "**Some** other places are B, C, and D" you leave open the possibility that places X, Y, and Z are also beautiful.

Comment: Sorry but I must rephrase your explanation. I do feel embarrassed but I really want to understand the difference between them. It's not easy. Thus Italy, France and Ireland are the most beautiful places in the world in my opinion. *The other places* that are just as beautiful  as Italy, France and Ireland are Scotland, Poland and Spain."   The other means these places are as beautiful. Only these ones: Scotland, Poland and Spain. *Some other places* or *other places* that are also beautiful are.... the list goes on. I can add Russia, Greece, etc to the list. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @Antonia your example works. By saying "Some other places that are **also** beautiful" you make those other places not as beautiful as the ones you listed before (the **other** "most beautiful" places). Also, it is a little awkward to say I/F/P are the most beautiful, and then say S/P/S are "just as" beautiful; you can't really have two levels of "the most."

Comment: You said "by saying  "other or some other places" I mean "other or some other places" are also unusual and beautiful like the places I listed" do you mean "other" and "some other" mean the same? It's in your first comment.  Thank you so much for answering question again.

Comment: @Antonia yes, "other" or "some other" are indefinite ("some" is the plural of "a/an"). "The other" is definite.

Comment: Thank you!!! :)